# ssmtp doesn't recognize ctrl+d

Tags: command-line, sendmail, ssmtp

I'm trying to send emails from an ubuntu-server (14.04.2 LTS) via the command-line and later inside small scripts. To do so, I want to use ssmtp with an external mailserver, inside the network, that doesn't need any authentication. Meaning there is a smtp-server (`external-server.com:25`) on another host, which I want to use to send mails. Since my host and the smtp-server are in the same network I can access the smtp-server without any authentication.

Therefore I configured ssmtp to use that external server, here is my ssmtp.conf:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=devnull@external-server.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=external-server.com:25

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=external-server.com

# The full hostname
#hostname=

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
#FromLineOverride=YES

#Settings for sending logfiles as devnull@external-server.com
AuthUser=devnull@external-server.com
AuthPass=
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

I can now call `ssmtp mymail@gmx.de`  and type in a message like this:

```
To: mymail@gmx.de
From: devnull@external-server.com
Subject: Test

Lorem ipsum ...
```

If I now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> simply nothing happens, I can literally wait for minutes. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to be ignored. Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works.

The `mail.err`-log is empty and `mail.log` just states

```
Mar 23 14:53:50 ubuntu-server sSMTP[2810]: Creating SSL connection to host
```

I also verified, that a connection is started using tcpdump.
Therefore the only problem I can point out is, that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> seems to be ignored.
Does anyone know this problem or even better a solution?

**EDIT**

Actually the problem was, that the `AuthUser` field wasn't empty and that other subnets were allowed to use the smtp-server, but not my subnet.

It was also very to uncomment FromLineOverride=YES, thus users could use their own mailaddresses.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/10/21/sending-email-from-your-system-with-ssmtp/

Comment: Could a lack of patience be the problem?

Comment: @ElderGeek I did the configuration according to the tutorial you posted. And I actually waited for about a minute after pressing `Ctrl + D` I was also still able to type characters after pressing `Ctrl + D`

Comment: If the mailserver is "inside your network", wouldn't that be considered an internal server?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and clarify "external mailserver, inside the network," It's a bit confusing and you may receive far better answers than mine if you do so.

Comment: After reading your edit I'm afraid I'm even more confused. Do you even need TLS between servers on your own local network?

Comment: It isn't the point that I need it, but the server is just reachable on two ports, 25:TLS and 465:SSL It is that way because the server is reachable from the internet as well. I could ask if there is another open port that doesn't need SSL/TLS. But I'm still not sure whether SSL/TLS is the problem. Could it be a problem, if a firewall blocks some ports from the external server to my server? Meaning I open a connection from my server to the external server using port 25 on the external server. Does there have to be an open port from the external server to me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm by no means an expert on this topic, however your configuration appears to be missing:

```
TLSCert
The file name of an RSA certificate to use for TLS, if required.
TLSKey
The file name of an RSA key to use for TLS, if required.
TLS_CA_File
A file of trusted certificates for validating the server, if required.
TLS_CA_Dir
A directory of trusted certificates for validating the server, if required.
```

I would assume these are required if using TLS

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf

Comment: I will give it a try. Do you know a good source for the TLS_CA files? I will first try with just the last option, because the first two look like they are just needed if I want to receive mails as well.

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I'll google it.

Comment: I did a little search myself. I think it depends on the root authority. For example for GeoTrust they can be found here: https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/ I think I know which certificate is the one I need.

Comment: More info on TLS can be found here: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch04.html and here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work

Comment: I tried setting the TLS_CA_File, after some errors I found out, that the online manpage at linux.die.net is outdated. Noew there is just `TLSCert` left as argument. But after I was able to actually set the parameter the behaviour stayed the same. But I noticed that the terminal seems to recognize the `Ctrl + D`, because the cursor stops blinking for a moment.